Third party sdk, android studio
I have an application and I have a third party sdk which is a transaction app, I want to get back to my result fragment if the result is successful. If it's cancelled or not successful, I want to get back to the first fragement. how can I do that?
  fun initView() {
        binding.apply {
            button.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_to_price_Enter_Fragment)
            }

            val args = arguments
            val amount = args?.getString("amount")
            val trace = args?.getString("trace")
            val rrn = args?.getString("rrn")
            val status = args?.getString("status")

            val statusText = if (status == "00") "success" else "fail"
            tvResult.text = "transaction : $statusText"
            tvPrice.text = "$amount rial"
            tvTrackingCode.text = trace
        }
     }


https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Try using popBackStack when you want to go back. Here official doc
navController.popBackStack(R.id.destinationId, true)

on success you can navigate to fragment as
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_to_success)

